# Deploy to external docker swarm

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

I have a Jenkinsfile in which I build a docker image and push it to an external private registry. If I were to manually update my docker swarm, I would do this:

```
docker use <context>
docker service update <service_name> --image <image_name>
```

However, inside the Jenkins build pipeline I don't have access to that external context. How can I update my docker swarm service anyway?